# DialogFlow with Android

Tags: java, android, dialogflow-es

I'm making an app with Android Studio (Java) and Dialogflow V2. I want to speak with the app and the message I said goes to Dialogflow and it answers me. The thing is that all I can find is that the user types the message and it is sent to Dialogflow.

Does someone know how to do it? How to convert the speak to message in the DialogFlow V2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1:** First of all, convert your users' text from a speech by `RecognizerIntent`. This [tutorial](https://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-speech-to-text-tutorial/) will be helpful for this.

**Step 2:** Then do your rest of the tasks for **DialogFlow** with the text getting from the speech.

Comment: With the Dialogflow V2 it is said that intent has a private access

Comment: Make a string first by google voice recognizer which belongs to an android phone. Then use the string in Dialogflow.

Comment: But I can't send the string by Intent as It is said in the tutorial. I found this: https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/how/detect-intent-stream?hl=es-419#detect-intent-stream-java

Comment: Do you see the answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52852519/dialogflow-detection-intent-from-audio

Answer (score 0):

Dialogflow can use Cloud Text-to-Speech to generate speech responses. The dependencies required for that are mentioned in this Dialogflow [article](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-android-client).

If you are using any third-party integration like Kommunicate with Dialogflow. Then add the below settings in Login success callback, find more details [here](https://docs.kommunicate.io/docs/android-customization#speech-to-text-and-text-to-speech-support).

```
KmPrefSettings.getInstance(contextOrActivityName.this)
        .enableSpeechToText(true)
        .enableTextToSpeech(true)
        .setSendMessageOnSpeechEnd(true);
```